# Immigration officer Questions if you are going for interviews

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

I'm from commonwealth country and I have applied for the UK military. I'm at the stage where medical was done a couple of days before, and now I'm just waiting for a call for interview dates which isn't confirmed.

I have already booked my ticket, which isn't refundable, and I'm flying on the 29th of May so I have some email as proof, which shows that the purpose of the visit is genuine, and I have got my visitor visa on the base of my  interviews. But, I'm little worried as I have all the documents and emails from my recruiter centre showing that the purpose of the visit is genuine but little worry for interviews dates as they might ask me for that...  I have already reservation of my return ticket and friend address where I'm going to stay etc.

Does anybody have experience with this, if yes kindly suggest what documents will be required and what type of questions the immigration officer will ask??

Comment: Could you please clarify why you've bought non-refundable tickets when you are unsure of the interview dates? You're flying on 29 May, but when is your return flight booked for? What are your options if the interviews don't happen between those dates? Thanks.

Comment: My return date is on 14 June. I have six month valid visa and it's mutiple I can go and come back whenever I want...

Comment: One of the first questions the immigration officer will ask is "How long will you be staying in the UK?"  If you cannot supply a firm answer to that question the landing interview may get very difficult very quickly.

Comment: You say you got your Visa on the basis of attending interviews to join the UK Military, you also say you're going to visit a friend. My concern is that if you arrive in the UK on 29th May and cannot show the Immigration Officer firm evidence of an interview between your arrival on 29th May and your departure on 14th June they may consider that there has been a change of purpose; and this could invalidate your Visa